# Ionic emulate android 404 with firebase

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic3, angularfire5

I'm currently using angularfire along with the ionic framework and it's working great in the browser but when I go to emulate it in android emulate I keep getting 404's to any firebase endpoints. In my config.xml I have

`<access origin="*" />`

so I would think that would work fine but I'm still getting a 404. Has anyone else gotten past this issue or some ideas on how to solve it?